# SQL Server : populate table in 15 minute intervals

Tags: sql-server, datetime, intervals, populate

I need to populate a table in SQL Server with an `ID` column and a `TimeValue` column with 15 minute intervals between `01/01/2000` and `01/01/2020`.

It seems there must e a simple way to do it, but I'm new to T-SQL and can't find any easy way to achieve this.

i.e.

```
ID         Timevalue           
------------------------------
      0    01/01/2000 00:00:00
      1    01/01/2000 00:15:00
      2    01/01/2000 00:30:00
   ...      ...                
 701280    01/01/2020 00:00:00
```

If you're interested this table is being used to join with a table with timestamps and values - the joined table may/may not have blanks for some intervals but shouldn't do any grouping/averaging if multiple values appear between say 01:00-01:15 it should only report the value at 01:00 and 01:15. There needs to be a fixed number of output rows so it "syncs" with other tables which are being produced in Excel.

If you can think of a better way of doing this I would be keen to know!

Comment: Since there is no certainty that there is a value for the timevalue you seek, I think SQL isn't the answer here, and a coding language is your way to solve it

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [numbers table](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

```
WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP (10000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
)
SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n), [timestamp] = DATEADD(MINUTE, n, '00:00:00')
FROM Numbers
WHERE n % 15 = 0
```

Comment: I would remove the filter `where n % 15 = 0` and instead multiply `n` by fifteen, so `dateAdd(mi, n * 15, dateFromParts(2000, 1, 1))`. Why throwing away most of the generated numbers? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

let's keept it simple, as there is always another looking our code ;)

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME  

SET @start = '20000101';
SET @end = '20000105';    --SET @end = '20200101';

WHILE @start < @end
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Table1
  VALUES (@start)

  SET @start = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @start)
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your time intervals using [Recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (ID INT IDENTITY(0,1), TIMEVALUE DATETIME);

DECLARE @start DATETIME;
DECLARE @end DATETIME;

SET @start = '20000101';
SET @end = '20200101';

WITH CTE_DT AS 
(
    SELECT @start AS DT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,15,DT) FROM CTE_DT
    WHERE DT< @end
)
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT DT FROM CTE_DT
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9d9a/2)**